# Is there any difference in the First Contact responses?

Tags: stellaris

So I've just made contact with some aliens and they aren't trying to horribly murder me.

I've got 3 options for responses for some of the different traits my species has. None of them show any effects in the hover text, is there a difference?

Are my people just boring that they don't have special responses?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

No, it's just flavor text depending on your governments ethics. if you chose 3 ethics, you'll get 3 responses based on any combination of two. If you are fanatical, you'll get three options as well, one based on both of your ethic aspects, two based on one.

None however will influence the opinion of the other empire nor will they have any effect on future interactions.

Comment: they should realy remove the choices and make it into an "ok" button.