# How does First-Contact choices affect relationship in Stellaris?

Tags: stellaris

Our empire just made first contact with another empire.

When that happened, we were some given first contact choices:

[image]

We made many contacts before and are wondering if these choices have any effect at all?

Comment: This has already been answered here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/265701/is-there-any-difference-in-the-first-contact-responses

Comment: Indeed, 10x, I'll close the question.